# Send a csv file to fastAPI and get a new file back

Tags: python, pandas, api, fastapi

I have this very simple code that gets a dictionary as imput and returns back a dictionary as well:

```
app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    user_name: dict


@app.post("/")
def main(user: User):
   ## some processing
   return user
```

I'm calling this with the following python code:

```
import requests
import json 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
data = {}
data["user_name"] = df.to_dict()
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
resp
```

Now, I want to do something similar but instead of sending the data with a request from python
I want to upload a local file send it to the API and get a processed .csv file back.

Now I have the following code to upload a file:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse


app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    user_name: dict

@app.post("/files/")
async def create_files(files: List[bytes] = File(...)):
    return {"file_sizes": [len(file) for file in files]}


@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
async def create_upload_files(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return {"filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
<body>
<form action="/files/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="files" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)
```

[image]

This allows me to select and load a file:
[image]

But when I click on send, I'm redirected to: http://localhost:8000/uploadfiles/  and get the following error:

```
{"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}
```

How can I send the file for procesing to the API and get a file back as a response?

Comment: how did you read the data from files or upload files? the request will return an obkect, how did you transform it to dataframe?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804)

Answer (score 4):

I copied your code and I got the same error. After going through the [FastAPI documentation for requesting files](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/), it is mentioned that

> To receive uploaded files, first install python-multipart.
>
> E.g. pip install `python-multipart`.
>
> This is because uploaded files are sent as "form data".

After installing the library `python-multipart`, the code worked perfectly.

**References:**

- https://andrew-d.github.io/python-multipart/